# Unable to extend interface in Typescript with data property on even with the same data type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a strange issue with *Typescript* (using Visual Studio 2012 and TypeScript v0.9.5) that I hope someone can clear up.

The following code works fine:

```
interface IA {
    data: any;
}

interface IB {
    data: any;
}

interface IC extends IA, IB { }
```

However, when using the declaration for `JQueryEventObject` as follows:

```
interface JQueryEventObject extends BaseJQueryEventObject, 
    JQueryInputEventObject, JQueryMouseEventObject, JQueryKeyEventObject,
    JQueryPopStateEventObject { }
```

and where the BaseJQueryEventObject declaration is:

```
interface BaseJQueryEventObject extends Event {
    data: any;
    delegateTarget: Element;
    isDefaultPrevented(): boolean;
    isImmediatePropogationStopped(): boolean;
    ...
}
```

when I try to do this:

```
interface IMyInterface {
    data: any;
}

interface IMyCombinedInterface extends JQueryEventObject, IMyInterface { }
```

it complains with the following message:

Interface `IMyCombinedInterface` cannot simultaneously extend types `JQueryEventObject` and `IMyInterface`: Types of property `data` of types `JQueryEventObject` and `IMyInterface` are not identical.

Anyone know if I'm doing something wrong or is this a bug maybe?

Comment: This seems like a bug to me.

Comment: This compiles for me using 0.9.1.1  What version of TS are you compiling against

Comment: It compiles, but VS complains (sorry, will update the post to state that I'm using visual studio).  I'm using v0.9.5 of TS.

Comment: I have just upgraded to 0.9.5.  I still don't get the error.  As some diagnostics, declare 2 variables typed to IMyInterface and JQueryEventObject and see what intellisense gives for the data property of each variable.  I would also suggest you verify you have the latest version of jquery.d.ts from DefinitelyTyped.  Some older versions of the d.ts file have been liked to this compiler error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following compiles fine with the Latest TypeScript (1.5) + IDE shows no errors :

```
interface JQueryEventObject extends BaseJQueryEventObject,
    JQueryInputEventObject, JQueryMouseEventObject, JQueryKeyEventObject { }{ }

interface IMyInterface {
    data: any;
}

interface IMyCombinedInterface extends JQueryEventObject, IMyInterface { }
```

## So

Was a bug but has since been fixed.